# Angular return me an Array as undefined, but I had defined previously

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, undefined, subscribe

I'm trying to use Google Books API. Firstly I created the interfaces that worked properly, then I created a method which return me an Array with a list of Books.

```
    public getBooks(): Observable<Book[]>{
        return this.http.get<Book[]>('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=filibusterismo');
    
      }
```

(I had added the element which I want to search, "filibusterismo", in order to avoid mistakes, but I would change later.)

Then, I want to use the Array of Book, but I can not use a ngFor loop because getBook return me an observable Array of Books instead of an Array of Books. This was my original constructor

```
   books:Book[];
     constructor(private GoodreadsService:GoodreadsService) { }
   
     ngOnInit() {
      this.libro=this.GoodreadsService.getBooks();
   }
```

I had tried to fix this using async.

`*ngFor="let book of books | async"`

But I have the same problem. So reading post in SO I learnt that I have to use subscribe in the ngOnInit(),  like this.

```
     this.GoodreadsService.getBooks().subscribe(res=>{this.books=res},
          error => { // on failure
            console.log('Error Occurred:');
          });
```

The problem, is that whereas I does not return me any kind of error, if I write

`console.log(this.libro1);`

The console say that the array is undefined, whereas I had defined it as an array of Book. Furthermore, I still can not use an ngFor.

I also had tried to map the getBook method, in order that return me an Array instead of an observable array, but I could not do it in spite of reading a lot of question in SO.

So, would somebody tell me how can I fix this issue, in order I could use an ngFor in the HTML?

My HTML is this

```
    <p>busqueda works!ss </p>
    <table>
      <thead>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Indexs</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <div *ngFor="let book of books | async">
            <h1  >
                <p>prueba</p>
            </h1>
          </div>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you try using the `subscribe` method in the constructor?

Comment: Using `| async` or `.subscribe` *is* how you can get the value from the observable to `ngFor` loop over it. It's not clear where you've been trying to `console.log` the value without a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I think not, but maybe I just have to leanr more. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you need to do it. Initialize the API call and subscribe to accordingly in order to send the request. After the response is returned then iterate over the items over it.

> Please refer to the working sample stackblitz attached [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-angular-tutorial-app-5lna15?file=src/app/app.component.html).

**Sample component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { SampleService } from "./sample.service";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  books: any;
  constructor(public sample: SampleService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sample.getBooks().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.items)
      this.books = data.items;
    });
  }
}
```

**Sample HTML :**

```
<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <div *ngFor="let book of books">
            <h4>
                <p>kind : {{book.kind}}</p>
        <p>Id : {{book.id}}</p>
        <p>etag : {{book.etag}}</p>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank, but if I write data.items, it return me an error saying that items does not exist in Book(which its true). And if I try to put a Book parameter, like kind, it return me also an error.